# Generating a sequence using user input and database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to create a sequence of numbers using values stored in a database and user input. I have a webapp that is generating barcodes. I know my issue lies with my nested for loop. Whatever value I have stored on my database, I want the user to start from that number and generate the amount of barcodes entered by the user starting from that number. The loop iterates strangely where it will not generate any images if the value entered is less than the what is in the database. If I enter a value greater than what is in the database it will only generate a number of images that is the difference between what the use entered and what's in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE AccountTable
(
   RowID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
   AccountID varchar(2),
   AccountName varchar(50),
   SeqNum int,
   SeqDate datetime
)  

protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
(
     CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
     System.Globalization.DateTimeStyle style = DateTimeStyle.None;
     DateTime dt;
     DateTime.TryParseExact(datepicker.Text, "mmddyyyy", provider, style out dt);
     int i = Int32.Parse(amount.Text);

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Text = "SELECT MAX(SeqNum) as k FROM AccountTable;";
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    foreach(List item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {    
        conn.Open();
        var k = Convert.Int31(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        for(int n = k; n <= i; n++) 
        {

           if (item.Selected)
           {

              System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
              string barcode_label = item.Text + "QTY:___________"


             string barode_data = item.Value + datepicker.Text + n.ToSTring("D2");

             Bitmap dynImage = DrawBarcode(barcode_data, barcode_label)

             MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

             dynImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

             byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

             Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

             img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);

             panel1.Controls.Add(img);

             double spacing;

             double mg = 5;

            spacing = img.Width.Value + mg;

         }

     } 
     conn.Close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the loop condition be `n <= i + k`? Using real variable names would help clarify some of these things.

Comment: This might help... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/emulate-a-tsql-sequence-via-a-stored-procedure it does create unique ids based on user input via SQL Stored Procedure.

Comment: Can you explain what is the relationship between the items checked and the number of loops required by your i variable. If an item is not checked then the inner loop is skipped thus you generate the exact number of images only if you check all the items in the CheckBoxList (after fixing the loop condition as explained by @itsme86)

Comment: The checkbox list has choices which are strings, if I choose items in the checkbox list and enter a value in my text box as well as enter a date, it will generate a barcode and the data in the barcode is a concatenation of The string selected in the checkboxlist, the date, and a sequence of numbers entered in the textbox. so if I want 5 barcodes, I enter 5 as well as the other information and I get 5 barcodes. It works just fine, but I'm implementing a database so I can implement a sequence that way.

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF ALL THAT IS HOLY @itsme86 that's all I wanted! I just kept trying every other way and I couldn't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: @Steve brings up a good point. The outer loop is checked thus, it will generate the values of the sequence only of what was checked before. So what I'm asking here then is not the ideal way to do it.